# jquery accordian hide show visible event trigger

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

I have coded a basic accordian which toggles elements in a form using next and previous buttons. The accordian is working as designed and does not require any editting.
I am now required to fire a a function only once when a a designated accordian pane is displayed. The senario being that the trggered function should only fire once even if a user revisits that pane.

This has me slighlty confused about how to go about doing this using jquerys live event and or visible psuedocode.

Any direction.help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your code looks like, but assuming you have some sort of callback for when a panel becomes active, with some sort of reference to a DOM node representing that panel, you could do something like this:

```
if(! $(panel).data('initialized') ) {
   // initialize panel
   $(panel).data('initialized', true);
}
```

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that a callback in say a fadeout effect would be sufficient? [http://jsfiddle.net/designmode/AdPWv/](http://jsfiddle.net/designmode/AdPWv/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the accordionchange event, to bind to it you can do this

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) { alert('hello world'); });
```

Replace the  selector $('.ui-accordion') with the unique path to the accordion you want to bind to.

## Update to cater for the once only

In your method use

```
$('.ui-accordion').unbind('accordionchange');
```

to ensure it only fires once.

Comment: The way I understood the question, the code should be evaluated only once *per panel*